# Best way to query all documents from a mongodb collection in a reactive way w/out flooding RAM

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rxjs, reactivex

I want to query all the documents in a collection in a reactive way. The [collection.find()](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/api/Collection.html#find) method of the mongodb nodejs driver returns a cursor that fires events for each document found in the collection. So I made this:

```
function giant_query = (db) => {
    var req = db.collection('mycollection').find({});   
    return Rx.Observable.merge(Rx.Observable.fromEvent(req, 'data'),
                               Rx.Observable.fromEvent(req, 'end'),
                               Rx.Observable.fromEvent(req, 'close'),
                               Rx.Observable.fromEvent(req, 'readable'));
}
```

It will do what I want: fire for each document, so I can treat then in a reactive way, like this:

```
Rx.Observable.of('').flatMap(giant_query).do(some_function).subscribe()
```

I could query the documents in packets of tens, but then I'd have to keep track of an index number for each time the observable stream is fired, and I'd have to make an observable loop which I do not know if it's possible or the right way to do it.

The problem with this cursor is that I don't think it does things in packets. It'll probably fire all the events in a short period of time, therefore flooding my RAM. Even if I buffer some events in packets using Observable's buffer, the events and events data (the documents) are going to be waiting on RAM to be manipulated.

What's the best way to deal with it n a reactive way?

Comment: From the [documentation](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/tutorials/streams/), the find method is a stream. Do you have a reason to think it fetches all docs to the client in one go?

Comment: @RichardMatsen no, but how fast it does? Because I need to post each document to the internet, so if it returns me 100 documents in 0.1 secs, it'll be 100 queries every 0.1 secs. If I delay the queries in groups of tens, for example, then it's ok, but what about all the documents that will be waiting to be sent?

Comment: normally on a loop, there's a function that consumes a buffer, thus reading in packets of 4096 bytes for example. In reactive, however, there's nothing consuming the documents, they arrive without asking if it's ok

Comment: Yes, I see what you are saying - if the db events behave like, say mouse events, they keep happening regardless of consumption rate. There seems to be a `cursor.next()`, perhaps you could `Observable.of(cursor.next())` instead of `Observable.fromEvent(...)`

Comment: Or perhaps `Rx.Observable.fromPromise(cursor.next())`, see [Magnitus-/mongodb-cursor-observable](https://github.com/Magnitus-/mongodb-cursor-observable/blob/master/index.js#L15)

Comment: Why don't you use BulkOperations (with initializeUnorderedBulkOp) ? You can then freely add as many items as you want and execute the .exec() on the bulk whenever you want.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not an expert on mongodb, but based on the examples I've seen, this is a pattern I would try.

I've omitted the events other than data, since throttling that one seems to be the main concern.

```
var cursor = db.collection('mycollection').find({});  

const cursorNext = new Rx.BehaviourSubject('next');  // signal first batch then wait
const nextBatch = () => {
  if(cursor.hasNext()) {
    cursorNext.next('next');
  }
});

cursorNext
  .switchMap(() =>                            // wait for cursorNext to signal
     Rx.Observable.fromPromise(cursor.next())  // get a single doc
       .repeat()                               // get another
       .takeWhile(() => cursor.hasNext() )     // stop taking if out of data
       .take(batchSize)                        // until full batch
       .toArray()                              // combine into a single emit
  )
  .map(docsBatch => {
    // do something with the batch
    // return docsBatch or modified doscBatch
  })
  ... // other operators?
  .subscribe(x => {
    ...
    nextBatch();
  });
```

I'm trying to put together a test of this Rx flow without mongodb, in the meantime this might give you some ideas.

Comment: the problem with this design is that I need to insert a call to process batch, I cannot use it inside another stream of observables. If I return just everything up to the .toArray()), then I cannot call cursorNext. I'm disapointed with Rx Observables, it's not trivial to make a loop...

Comment: Can you give an idea of what 'another stream of observables' looks like? I presented this in a similar way to your original code. The key difference is that it needs some way to signal that all downstream processing is complete. I'd say that an open ended pipe will never do that, you need the feedback (firing cursorNext) to produce the required throttling.

Comment: It may be possible to do it with the call to cursorNext.next() inside the `subscribe()`.

Comment: I wanted to plug it in another stream, like: Rx.Observable.just().map(x=>return_batch(x)).do(do_more_things_with_batch).do(do_other_things).map(map_to_something).subscribe()

Comment: Why didn't you simply add repeat() at the end, instead of doing nextBatch()?

Comment: It is possible to do loops in rxjs using expand, repeat, takeWhile etc

Comment: @Guerlando - a repeat at the end might fire before batch processing has completed. You mention **I need to post each document to the internet** which involves some async. Therefore you need a signal mechanism to be sure the batch is done.

Comment: The above can most likely be simplified, for example db.collection(...).find().batchSize() might eliminate the repeat().takeWhile() operators. However, I need a test environment or some constructive feedback on what works and what does not.

Comment: @RichardMatsen I have problems understanding repeat. Tried to search about "reactivex repeat" and I can only find that it repats sequences, so it should work

Comment: Yes, you are correct that it repeats sequences, but my concern is you won't have a pure sequence, since sending a doc to the internet is an async operation. It might work if you do something like `.mergeMap(doc => http.post(doc) )` - this should hold up the stream until the http.post completes.

Comment: @RichardMatsen mergeMap is the same as flatMap, right? So if I repeat after mergeMap it will redo everything for a new element of the cursor?

Answer (score 0):

You also might wanna check my solution without using of `rxJS`:
[Mongoose Cursor: http bulk request from collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56752695/mongoose-cursor-http-bulk-request-from-collection/61319245#61319245)